# How to make custom file in Groovy

Tags: git, file, text, groovy

I have a text file that consists of a series of headers, each of which has a list of paths to files corresponding to that header

```
10gen
C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\mongodb\mongo\client\gridfs.cpp
C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\mongodb\mongo\client\model.cpp
10gen .SH
C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\mongodb\mongo\debian\mongod.1
C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\mongodb\mongo\debian\mongo.1

etc...
```

I am trying to create a new file for each of the headers, and the file will contain the related paths that are listed under the header in the original big file.  I am a total newb to Groovy; how can I automate the creation these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def output
new File("input.txt").eachLine { line ->
    if (isHeader(line)) {
        output?.close()
        output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(line))
    } else {
        output?.println(line)
    }
}
output?.close()
```

The `isHeader` method should return true if the line is a header.

Comment: Thanks ataylor.  How does `isHeader` know if the line is a header?  Also, what are the `?` doing here?  I can see the general idea here and it is great, but I'm having trouble implementing it.  what is the format for the file in `input.txt`, something like C:\\temp\\dove.txt  ?

Comment: The `?` make the calls null safe, i.e. if output is null, then the method isn't called.  It's a shortcut around checking for null before each call.  For the file format I'm using your example; `isHeader` depends on the details.  The file names don't have to have escaped backslashes since they are read from a file; they'd need them if they were string literals.

Comment: I should have worded this differently maybe, although from the lines of text I provided it might be obvious -- By "header" i just mean a title under which all of the related files are organized.  So from the example I provided, `10gen` would be the first "header" that I want to use as the title of the first file the groovy script creates.  In that file I want to store the two files listed under `10gen` ("C:\cygwin\home...).  Then the script will make a new file with the second "header" (`10gen .SH`) as a title, etc...

Comment: One way to implement `isHeader` might be `def isHeader(filename) { !new File(filename).exists() }` to use any line isn't the name of an existing file as a header.

Comment: Originally I thought I'd just stumble through this with a few loops that looked for "`C:\`".  If that wasn't the first thing encountered, then make a file sharing the title of that line.  Then keep going, putting all files beginning with "`C:\`" in this parent file, until another "header" is encountered and the process starts again.  This is crude, I know, but like I said, I am a newb!  Your method seems way more elegant but I'm having a bit of trouble implementing it.  Thanks a lot though, I appreciate the help